# What is ALTER PROCEDURE used for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new on Databases. Could you explain the lines of this piece to me please? or give me a link to some documentation that will help me understand this code.
I only understood that the code is modifying the stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SetRequestStatus] 
    @requestId int,
    @status int,
    @statusnote nvarchar(max) = '',
    @Result nvarchar(2000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t_Request 
        SET StatusId = @status, 
        UpdatedStatusTime = GETDATE(), 
        StatusNote = @statusnote, 
        UpdatedDate = GETDATE() 
        WHERE Id = @requestId
    SET @Result = 'Success'
END
```

Comment: You pass an id and status info. It updates the table.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=sqlpool

Comment: A stored procedure is a piece of stored code. You can execute it and pass it parameters. When executed, this procedure updates a table called `t_Request`. After creating a procedure, sometimes you may want to modify the procedure. That's what `ALTER PROCEDURE` is - it allows you to change the stored procedure after it is created with `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I'm going to risk being a bit pedantic for this room and go through everything in detail, and this is definitely overkill. Here's the first part:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SetRequestStatus] 
    @requestId int,
    @status int,
    @statusnote nvarchar(max) = '',
    @Result nvarchar(2000) OUTPUT 
AS
```

This is the declaration for the stored procedure.  It is using `ALTER PROCEDURE` which assumes that the procedure already exists in the DB.  A stored procedure is roughly equivalent to a C function that returns void.  There's more to it, but that's the basic part.

This procedure has four arguments.  The first two are of type `int` (four bytes signed integer).  `nvarchar(max) =''` is a variable length character string in Unicode which can have a max length of 2Gbytes, and has a default value of empty string, which is not the same thing as `NULL`.  That distinction is very important, and you should look further into that.

The final argument `@Result nvarchar(2000) OUTPUT` is an output variable with a Unicode character set that has a maximum length of 2000 characters.

Moving on, `SET NOCOUNT ON;` turns off the row count from the later `UPDATE`.  Normally it isn't a good idea to set this to off, for performance and other reasons.  It should be set to ON.

Now on to the `UPDATE`

```
    UPDATE t_Request 
        SET StatusId = @status, 
        UpdatedStatusTime = GETDATE(), 
        StatusNote = @statusnote, 
        UpdatedDate = GETDATE() 
        WHERE Id = @requestId
```

This is updating the table t_Request.  It is setting the column StatusID with the passed in argument @status, StatusNote with the argument @statusnote,  UpdatedStatusTime with the time right now (`GETDATE()`)  likewise with the date on UpdatedDate.  Finally the UPDATE is restricted to those rows where `Id = @requestId`

The last thing the procedure does is assign 'Success' to `@Result`.  When this procedure is called in a script, any variable you pass in as the fourth argument will now contain 'Success'.

Like I said, this is way overkill, and far too detailed, but there you go.

Comment: Great writeup! Can you check the paragraph about `NOCOUNT`? The setting itself has the problem of signaling a negative and I think you've fallen into the trap of evaluating it incorrectly as a result.

Comment: You are correct, I goofed there.  Fixed.